# is there a way to find and return a property if it has a specific value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What I want is that in users query it returns the `email` `data` whenever `private` is false.

this is my scheme

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    private: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    data: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
})
```

I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work because it is not dynamic.

```
const user = await User.find({}, '-email.data')
```

the result I am looking for is this

```
[
  { _id: 0, email: { private: true } },
  { _id: 1, email: { private: false, data: 'email@email.com' } }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$cond` operator, check if `email.private` is `true` then return only `private` property otherwise full `email` object

```
const user = await User.find({},
{
  email: {
    $cond: [
      { $eq: ["$email.private", true] },
      { private: true },
      "$email"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3f8YtRIGhlx)